# Searching and printing XML using XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am searching an xml file that looks like this:

```
<producers>
  <producer>
    <name></name>
    <owner></owner>
    <phone></phone>
    <fax></fax>
    <overview></overview>
    <address>
      <civic></civic>
      <mailing></mailing>
      <town></town>
      <province></province>
      <postal></postal>
      <email></email>
      <website></website>
    </address>
    <products>
      <product>Salmon</product>
      <product>Trout</product>
    </products>
    <exports>
      <region>Canada</region>
      <region>United States</region>
    </exports>
  </producer>
```

Then I search for it like so:

```
$upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÂÆÇÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜ"; 
$lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzàâæçèéêëîïôœùûü";

$region = "Canada";

$node = $xml->xpath('//producers/producer/exports[descendant::*[contains(translate(text(), "'.$upper.'", "'.$lower.'"), "'.$region.'")]]');
```

The problem is I want to be able to print the entire producer. But all I have access to at this point is what is contained in any descendants of exports. Is there a way I can travel back a couple of nodes to retrieve the full listing of the desired producer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to put /../../ at the end of your xpath. Something like this

```
$node = $xml->xpath('//producers/producer/exports[descendant::*[contains(translate(text(), "'.$upper.'", "'.$lower.'"), "'.$region.'")]]/../../');
```

Comment: This fits with what I need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath, it is more readable:

```
$node = $xml->xpath('//producers/producer[exports/region[contains(translate(text(), "'.$upper.'", "'.$lower.'"), "'.$region.'")]]');
```

It will select desired `producer`.

Comment: This does look cleaner but unfortunately, I am doing several different types of searches with the one xpath statement. But this does help me understand this a bit better. Thanks.